# json_encode contains HTML tags and JSON.parse is failing on Javascript

Tags: json

I am new to PHP and Javascript. When I try to encode MYSQL  output in PHP which conatians HTML tags,  the output on the Javascript side fails to parse. However if I encode the MYSQL output which does not contain HTML tags it works perfectly fine.
Is there any way to jsn_encode MYSQL data in PHP and remove the HTML part .

My code is something like this

```
    render_template('header');/* this is HTML files rendering header*/
    render_template('logo'); /* this is HTML file rendering logo */
    render_template('menu');/* This is HTML file rendering menu */
   /* the following file does SQL extraction */ 
   render_controller('ExtractSchoolinfo');

 /* JSON encode fails as the above lines contains HTML tags */
   print_r(json_encode(($_SESSION['schooldata'])));
     unset($_SESSION['schooldata']);
```

Thanks for all your help

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php to encode the array or string:

```
PHP: json_encode(ARRAY, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

In javascript to decode the same:

```
JS: var d = $.parseJSON(content);
```